# How to set limit for joined mysql table?

Tags: node.js, mysql-5.7, node-mysql2

I'm trying to combine data from 3 tables with below query

```
SELECT `media_category`.id as cat_id,
        `media_category`.category_name as cat_name,
        `video`.`id` as vid_id,
        `video`.`name` as vid_name,
        `screenshots`.name as screenshot_name
        FROM `media_category`
        LEFT JOIN video
        ON `media_category`.id = `video`.`category_id`
        LEFT JOIN screenshots
        ON `video`.id = `screenshots`.`media_id`
        WHERE `screenshots`.name NOT LIKE '%\_%'
```

**version: mysql 5.7**

It workes well. But I need to limit the rows getting from `video` table to `LIMIT 10` per category

Any idea for that?

Comment: What is the expected outcome? 10 videos per category, or 10 videos overall?

Comment: @josh.trow 10 videos per category

Comment: you find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group

Comment: Your left outer join is not working properly, since you have a predicate in the `WHERE` clause. They are silently converted to INNER joins.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which MySQL version you are using so I'll assume it's MySQL 8.x.

In MySQL 8.x you can use the `DENSE_RANK()` function to identify the rows you want. Then a simple predicate will remove the ones you don't want.

For example, if we want to limit to 2 rows of `b` on each `a` (irrespective of rows in `c`), you can do:

```
select *
from (
  select
    a.id,
    b.id as bid,
    dense_rank() over(partition by a.id order by b.id) as drank,
    c.id as cid
  from a
  left join b on b.aid = a.id
  left join c on c.bid = b.id
) x
where drank <= 2
```

Result:

```
id  bid  drank     cid
--  ---  -----  ------
 1   11      1     100
 1   11      1     101
 1   11      1     102
 1   11      1     103
 1   12      2     120
 2   20      1     200
 2   20      1     201
 2   21      2     202
 3   30      1  <null>
```

As you can see it shows only `11` and `12` for the id = 1, even though there are 5 total rows for it (all five are of rank 1 and 2). You can see the running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/58CsrvPezLzYvWBLhRGmfo/0). The data script for this example is:

```
create table a (id int primary key not null);

insert into a (id) values (1), (2), (3);

create table b (id int primary key not null, aid int references a (id));

insert into b (id, aid) values
  (11, 1), (12, 1), (13, 1), (14, 1),
  (20, 2), (21, 2),
  (30, 3);

create table c (id int primary key not null, bid int references b (id));

insert into c (id, bid) values
  (100, 11), (101, 11), (102, 11), (103, 11),
  (120, 12), (130, 13), (140, 14),
  (200, 20), (201, 20),
  (202, 21);
```

Comment: I changed the question tag to MySQL-5.7. Unfortunately that's quite of a different animal. As you say, this solution won't work there.